# How to transform the dataframe into label feature vector?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I am running a logistic regression modl in scala and I have a data frame like below:

df

```
+-----------+------------+
|x          |y           |
+-----------+------------+
|          0|           0|
|          0|          33|
|          0|          58|
|          0|          96|
|          0|           1|
|          1|          21|
|          0|          10|
|          0|          65|
|          1|           7|
|          1|          28|
+-----------+------------+
```

I need to tranform this into something like this

```
+-----+------------------+
|label|      features    | 
+-----+------------------+
|  0.0|(1,[1],[0])       |
|  0.0|(1,[1],[33])      |
|  0.0|(1,[1],[58])      |
|  0.0|(1,[1],[96])      |
|  0.0|(1,[1],[1])       |
|  1.0|(1,[1],[21])      |
|  0.0|(1,[1],[10])      |
|  0.0|(1,[1],[65])      |
|  1.0|(1,[1],[7])       |
|  1.0|(1,[1],[28])      | 
+-----------+------------+
```

I tried

```
 val lr = new LogisticRegression()
           .setMaxIter(10)
           .setRegParam(0.3)
           .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

      val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("x"))
  .setOutputCol("Feature")
  var lrModel=  lr.fit(daf.withColumnRenamed("x","label").withColumnRenamed("y","features"))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the `dataframe` as

```
+---+---+
|x  |y  |
+---+---+
|0  |0  |
|0  |33 |
|0  |58 |
|0  |96 |
|0  |1  |
|1  |21 |
|0  |10 |
|0  |65 |
|1  |7  |
|1  |28 |
+---+---+
```

And doing as below

```
val assembler =  new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("x", "y"))
  .setOutputCol("features")

  val output = assembler.transform(df).select($"x".cast(DoubleType).as("label"), $"features")
output.show(false)
```

Would give you result as

```
+-----+----------+
|label|features  |
+-----+----------+
|0.0  |(2,[],[]) |
|0.0  |[0.0,33.0]|
|0.0  |[0.0,58.0]|
|0.0  |[0.0,96.0]|
|0.0  |[0.0,1.0] |
|1.0  |[1.0,21.0]|
|0.0  |[0.0,10.0]|
|0.0  |[0.0,65.0]|
|1.0  |[1.0,7.0] |
|1.0  |[1.0,28.0]|
+-----+----------+
```

Now using `LogisticRegression` would be easy

```
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

val lrModel = lr.fit(output)
println(s"Coefficients: ${lrModel.coefficients} Intercept: ${lrModel.intercept}")
```

You will have output as

```
Coefficients: [1.5672602877378823,0.0] Intercept: -1.4055020984891717
```

Comment: It throws an error Vector Assembler does not support String type.Any idea why it throws this error?By the way the format is also different from which I reuqire to feed the model

Comment: where did you get `trip_status` from?

Comment: Apologize that's actually x only

Comment: I cannot `import sqlContext.implicits._` directly. When I searched it shows that I cannot do this in spark 2.0.0

Comment: how are you creating sqlContext ?

Comment: `val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DemandPrediction")
      conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      conf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000m")
      conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g");
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)` Am I supposed to use spark session

Comment: sparkSession is better :)

Comment: I am using  `val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("DemandPrediction")
  .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
  .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000m")
  .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g")
  .getOrCreate()` and read as `val df  = sparkSession.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("D:/Data.csv")` But still cannot import the `import sqlContext.implicits._` package

Comment: After you create sparkSession object you can do `val sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext
    import sqlContext.implicits._` . :)

Comment: are you using `import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler`? And are you doing exactly as in my answer? I still see `trip_status`

Comment: Oh now I got it. But a quick question the import is ok but now it throws a Vector Assembler does not support String type.I changed the code to val output = assembler.transform(df).select($"x".cast(DoubleTyp‌​e).as("label"), $"features".cast(DoubleType)) But that also throws same error

Comment: Sorry again it is x only.Yeah i imported import `org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler` but still getting the error.Is it because of the feature array mismatch type

Comment: can you share me the schema of your original dataframe? I guess they are of stringType.

Comment: why df5 to the transform? And can I see the printSchema of df3?

Comment: `val df  = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("D:/Data.csv") val df3=df.select("x", "y")   val output = assembler.transform(df3).select($"x".cast(DoubleType).as("label"), $"features".cast(DoubleType).as("features"))` Sorry that was a typo it is d3 only .The d3 is same as df in the question


`

Comment: yeah but I wanted to see the schema.

Comment: What do you mean my schema I am not aware of that.I just read from file and process it

Comment: just do `df.printSchema` and send it to me. schema is the structure of your dataframe without which a dataframe is not possible. its the same as schema of databases like mysql. :)

Comment: `root
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |-- y: string (nullable = true)`.Yes both the type are String because I do not parse them into other data type.I read from csv and process directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149536/discussion-between-ricky-and-ramesh-maharjan).